# Python virtualenv -> New python executable in venv/bin/python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm currently trying to install Sevabot with this tutorial: https://sevabot-skype-bot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ubuntu.html Everything is going fine until I need to install Sevabot. I can download the virtualenv.py file just fine but when I want to execute python virtualenv.py it returns a error.

> `~/sevabot$ python virtualenv.py venv
>   New python executable in venv/bin/python
>   Cannot find sdist setuptools-*.tar.gz
>   Cannot find sdist pip-*.tar.gz`

Weird thing is, I have done this 5 times without any problems. Always Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64. Already did a clean install several times.

```
~/sevabot$ uname -a
Linux sbvps01 2.6.32-5-openvz-amd64 #1 SMP Fri May 10 09:43:55 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Virtualenv is up to date:

```
easy_install virtualenv
Searching for virtualenv
Best match: virtualenv 1.7.1.2
Adding virtualenv 1.7.1.2 to easy-install.pth file
Installing virtualenv script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for virtualenv
Finished processing dependencies for virtualenv
```

Python version:

```
python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

Comment: This is a programming q&a site. You should ask this question at the sister site http://superuser.com/

Comment: Actually, Stackoverflow is helping me more in Linux then Superuser ever did. (For example, check the related items) I do understand your point tough so I want to apologize.

Comment: I understand your point, no need to apologize. It's maybe better to get help where you can get it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when you are not installing virtualenv/python using distribution packaging system. 
You might want to download files in https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tree/develop/virtualenv_support and run virtualenv with `--extra-search-dir virtualenv_support`

This is also explained here: http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#environment-variables-and-configuration-files.