# How to fix cannot find sdist pip-*.tar.gz

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, activepython

I was looking for some answer for this problem so I could not find anyone.
But in this images you can see my problem...

```
Cannot find sdist pip-*.tar.gz
```

But I followed the [installation guide](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#install-or-upgrade-pip) for Windows of course and I have the same problem...

So...could you help me?

This here is a img:
http://postimg.org/image/6fu9u3n37/

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339509/python-virtualenv-new-python-executable-in-venv-bin-python

Answer (score 6):

I tried upgrading the Virtual Environment and then was able to create a virtual environment successfully:

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```